# Looks like CKEDITOR parse HTML in <code> tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR 4 for my own website. recently, I noticed when I am editing my post, if there are HTML codes, it just prints as HTML. If the code was:

```
<code language-html ...>
    <h1>Helloworld</h1>
    <p>This is the post!</p>
</code>
```

I expected see:
[image]

But the result is really weird:
[image]

only I can imagine is CKEDITOR read the HTML code, and parse it. I removed CKEDITOR to normal "textarea" tag, and there was no problem (code tag contains h1, p).

I searched on the Google and find some solutions, but nothing worked to me.
Most I found was set the config above:

```
config.entities = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.entities_additional = '';
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
```

Still not working. Can anyone know about this issue?

p.s. I am using express framework as the server, and using jade template engine. I escaped the content when print: textarea#txtLog (name='log')!{log.text}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
htmlspecialchars($your_content, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

where you are displaying your post content after fetching it from the database.

Comment: i said: 'i am using express framework as the server, and using jade template engine' :(

Comment: Oh OK, then you need such similar function in your framework or template engine. I suggested in context to PHP. Sorry.